# Why doesn't UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit work in a UIImageView inside UIScrollView? See Image attached

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I can't understand... it was used to work before in other Apps I made with older IOS framework

Check the code below:

If I changed the contentMode to Left it displays the image...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrBook;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrBook;

@end



@synthesize scrBook;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrBook.frame.size;

    UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    //subview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
    subview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage alloc];
    currentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"model.jpg"];

    subview.image = currentImage;

    [self.scrBook addSubview:subview];

    self.scrBook.contentSize
    = CGSizeMake(self.scrBook.frame.size.width * 1, self.scrBook.frame.size.height);
}
```

UIViewContentModeLeft:

[image: UIViewContentModeLeft]

UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:

[image: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit]

Updates:
My last attempt was to uddate xcode to 4.5.2 and it doesn't work either, frustrating ...

Comment: What happens if you change your origin?

Comment: what do you mean, changing the origin?

Comment: Try logging the frame of the scroll view in `viewDidLoad`: `NSLog("%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrBook.frame))`.  Also, does your nib have Autolayout enabled?

Comment: I agree, try logging `srcBook.frame` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: good one, I will try to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but still don't know the reason, I upgraded my XCode to 4.5.1 to 4.5.2 and still nothing.

I duplicated one old project made in an older version of xcode (older than 4.5.1) using the 4.5.2 with the exaclty same code and it worked fine....

very weird.. I feel bad I took so many hours trying to find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to your problem, just a few optimizations...

```
UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage alloc];
currentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"model.jpg"];
```

There is no need for the first line, just do this:

```
UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"model.jpg"];
```

Also,

```
self.scrBook.contentSize
= CGSizeMake(self.scrBook.frame.size.width * 1, self.scrBook.frame.size.height);
```

can just be...

```
self.scrBook.contentSize = self.srcBook.frame.size;
```